# MySQL insert not working, syntax seems okay with phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with the following php syntax:

```
$sqlgo = "INSERT INTO invoice_qtydisc (`invoice_id`,`name`,`description`,`price`,`qty`,`discount`,`created`,`created_by`) VALUES ('$invoice_id','$product','$description','$price','$qty','$discount',NOW(),'$update_id')";
$dbconnect->query($sqlgo);
```

When PHP performed the code above, nothing being inserted into the db but when I echo $sqlgo and performed it in phpMyAdmin, everything seems to be fine. Here's the echo sample of the sql:

```
INSERT INTO invoice_qtydisc (`invoice_id`,`name`,`description`,`price`,`qty`,`discount`,`created`,`created_by`) VALUES ('118','Sport Socks','','20.00','1','0',NOW(),'1')
```

Did I miss anything? Hold on .. lemme paste the whole for loop just in case:

```
$item_maintain = array();
$test = 0;
$sqlgo = "";
for($i=0;$i<count($invoice_product);$i++) {
    if(!empty($invoice_product[$i])) {
        $product = addslashes($invoice_product[$i]);
        $description = addslashes($invoice_product_desc[$i]);
        $qty = trim($invoice_product_qty[$i]);
        $price = trim($invoice_product_price[$i]);
        if (!$invoice_product_discount[$i]) {
            $discount = 0;
        } else {
            $discount = trim($invoice_product_discount[$i]);
                    }
        if (!empty($item_current[$i])) {
            $dbconnect->query("UPDATE invoice_qtydisc SET name='$product', description='$description', price='$price', qty='$qty', discount='$discount', updated=NOW(), updated_by='$update_id' WHERE id='$item_current[$i]'");
            array_push($item_maintain, $item_current[$i]);
        } else {
            $sqlgo = "INSERT INTO invoice_qtydisc (`invoice_id`,`name`,`description`,`price`,`qty`,`discount`,`created`,`created_by`) VALUES ('$invoice_id','$product','$description','$price','$qty','$discount',NOW(),'$update_id')";
            $dbconnect->query($sqlgo);
            $dbconnect->query("INSERT INTO pin_board (title,message) VALUES ('title here','message here')");
            $test++;
        }
    }
}
```

The 2nd insert line into table "pin_board" worked flawlessly though.

Comment: Did you set `$dbconnect` somewhere (well it should be as the last query works)? Do you have any error displayed ?

Comment: there's only 1 instant of $dbconnect if that's what you wanna know :(

Comment: Roman .. there's no error displayed at all

Comment: You should start with rewriting your queries to prepared statements using bound variables. `addslashes()` and `trim()` do not protect your query from sql injection. Then you should setup your database connection to throw exceptions when something goes wrong so that you get a clear error message telling you what is wrong.